# Ajax Jquery on success change button value

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let me explain what I would like to do, I have a table row with a button on it.  When the user presses the button, it does an ajax call to a web service and on success I would like to change the text on the button to something else.

I have tried saving the value of this before the ajax call and on success pass in  this as a variable and try to change button text.

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/xgq2uumv/1/

The fiddle is just the idea of what I need to do, it doesn't run.

Here is the code  I have tried

```
$('#SendEmail').on('click', function () {  
 //save this to var
 var thisContext = this;

 sendEmail(bookingID, function (thisContext) {
     $(thisContext).val("hello");     
 }
});


 function sendEmail(id, onWebServiceSuccess) {
     //var data = JSON.stringify({ 'id': id });
     //webService.jsonPOST("ResendEmail", data, onWebServiceSuccess, onWebServiceFailed);
     return true;
 };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgq2uumv/6/) please. Based on the title of your question:

```js
function sendEmail(callback){
    callback();
}

$('#SendEmail').on('click', function () {  
 //save this to var
 var thisContext = this;
 //console.log(thisContext);
    
 sendEmail(function () {
     callback ("4", thisContext);
     console.log(thisContext);   
});
});

function callback(id, context) {
    console.log(id);
    var serverURL = "/echo/json/";
    $.ajax({
        url: serverURL,
        type:"POST",
        success: function(result){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(context).val("hello");  
                //return true;
            },1000);            
       },
        error: function(error){
        }
    });
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody class="tableBody">
     <tr>
         <td>
             <input type="button" value="Resend Email" id="SendEmail" class="btn btn-success" />
         </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the attribute `value`.

You can do this in jQuery with `$.attr(attribute, string)`:

```
$('#SendEmail').on( 'click' , function () {   
    $(this).attr( "value" , "hello" );
});
```

Alternatively, just use `$.val(string)`:

```
$('#SendEmail').on( 'click' , function () {   
    $(this).val( "hello" );
});
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gj7cLbx9/)

Comment: Hi, no I am trying to change the button value inside another function sendEmail(), which would be the result of my ajax call

Answer (score 0):

`SendEmail` is a input button and input button displays it's value attribute.
Therefore you need to update it's value to change the displayed text .

```
 $('#SendEmail').on('click', function () {   
      $(this).val("hello");
  });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/xgq2uumv/1/)

---

### Update

**Change**

```
$('#SendEmail').on('click', function () {  
         //save this to var
         var thisContext = this;            
         sendEmail(bookingID, function (thisContext) {//value of thisContext passed by function call
          $(thisContext).val("hello");  // thisContext is not #SendEmail
});
```

Here `thisContext` would not have refrence of `#SendEmail` .It is a function's parameter which is provided when function is invoked and if not provided then it will be `undefined`.

**To**

```
$('#SendEmail').on('click', function () {  //remove thisContext from parameter as it will be passed by function call
 //save this to var
 var thisContext = this;

 sendEmail(bookingID, function () {
     $(thisContext).val("hello");     
});
```

Comment: Hi, no I am trying to change the button value inside another function sendEmail(), which would be the result of my ajax call

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you defined the textual value of your button. Since you are using the `value` attribute for `<input type="button">` you should simply change your `$(this).text()` to `$(this).val()`, if instead you decide to use HTML5's `<button></button>` element, then keep using `$(this).text()`.

```
$('#SendEmail').on('click', function () {  
    //save this to var
    var thisContext = this;

    sendEmail(bookingID, function (thisContext) {
        $(thisContext).val("hello"); // <---- Using .val()
    } //  <---- You missed this
});
```

But it is also worth noting that Ajax calls are by nature assynchronous, so if you want to change the name of your button only when it has completed, you'll need a `.complete()` to call the name change.